# Are ability scores ever rolled for checks?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, ability-scores, skill-challenge

Are there checks against the ability scores? I do not mean skills.

Eg. In a tavern, a player is challenged to an arm wrestle. Is this resolved via a D20+STR or is this invalid because this is what skills are for?

Answer (score 6):

## Generally, No

It's hard to prove a negative across all rulebooks and APs, but I've never seen anything official call for any sort of check like this. You could easily homebrew it as you describe, but Athletics probably works well enough for arm wrestling. That's why my groups have used for arm wrestling, and it works well - it has the benefit of using proficiency (unless, of course, you're playing with Proficiency Without Level). Since the DCs in the game are generally set by level, I'd not advise doing D20+ability mod for anything more than trivial matters.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid all home-brew and find the core rules. Hopefully Ability Rolls are explicitly defined somewhere!

Comment: @Jarryd if you run a published adventure I'd be surprised if they were. Otherwise, I would be quite surprised to see anything explicitly defining them in Pathfinder 2e. Why do you need them explicitly defined? Perhaps that's a question we can better answer?

Comment: My party is bored and lost because we don't understand how to make our characters interact with the world. Excluding improvisational role play,  what are the rule based requests we may make to our GM while exploring environments and engaging with NPCs?

Comment: @Jarryd That's a very different question, I suggest ask it separately. However, the first answers are all going to be "Talk to your DM, try to come to some understandings on how you expect to play the game." If you do ask separately, give some examples of where/how you are stuck.

Comment: @Jarryd as Neil says, that’s a very different question, but the shortest version of the answer is that, in general, you can describe/do whatever you want, and your GM should (with your input) be able to determine what skill applies for the check in question. To use your arm wrestling example, that would clearly be an Athletics check. Which, for an untrained character is the same as a Strength check. And for a trained or better character, is a little better than a straight strength check.

Answer (score 2):

## Sort of...?

It's helpful here to look at what [the Core Rulebook has to say about Checks](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=314) in the most general of terms...

Specifically, let's look at Step 1; Identify the modifiers, bonuses, and penalties that apply. Your player has been challenged to an Arm Wrestling match! Well, that certainly involves Strength. And if your player doesn't have any training in Athletics, well, it generally stops there. Since they don't add their proficiency bonus in a thing they aren't trained in, yes, it's a 'straight strength check.'

But, if that player does have training in Athletics, well, they understand how to flex their muscles and properly apply force to their opponent. That represents some skill and deserves a bonus! Specifically, it deserves their *proficiency bonus*, in Athletics! Which is in fact what happens according to the rules. If they're untrained, but one of the other party members is trained, maybe they can use their training to take the Aid action and give some important advice at the start of the match, conferring a circumstance bonus.

To put all of this another way, 'checks against ability scores' is, essentially, another word for 'skill checks for which the character is untrained'. In any game, and especially at low levels, you may have opportunities for lots of these! But in general, just about anything a player can or will do, will generally be something that could, theoretically, benefit from *some* kind of training. At which point, Proficiency applies.